# Prove there are 2022 pairwise coprime intergers in $A$ or provide a counterexample

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, examples-counterexamples

An infinite sequence of positive integers $A = \{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ satsifies $2022 \geq a_{i + 1} - a_i \geq 1$. If there exists no infinite subsequence $B = \{b_n\}_{n{\geq 1}}$ of $A$ with $2022 \geq b_{i + 1} - b_i \geq 1$, such that all terms in $B$ have a common factor $k > 1$, then there exists 2022 pairwise coprime integers in $A$.

I don't understand this question, so I don't know where to start. If possible, can someone tell me how I should approach this? I tried listing some examples, and it all worked out, but I don't know how to do this question.

Comment: If there exists no infinite subsequence B such that all terms in B have a common factor $k>1$ means that $b_1 = 1, b_2 = 4, b_3 = 16, ...,$ is not a sequence in B, for example

Comment: @Alborz Yeah, I know this question seems pretty common sense; if you have no sequence in A that has a common factor, then all you are left with are relatively prime numbers. But I don't know how to show that rigorously.

Comment: Have you tried proof by contradiction? Maybe you will gain some insight from trying to find that contradiction

Comment: Another thing to try maybe is to work with the same result but for a smaller number than 2022.

Comment: @Alborz That was my approach, but I guess I suck that manipulating terms. I can't find anything useful because this sequence can be any number and allow repetition. Some base cases are true like if all numbers are equal to each other or the set contains all prime numbers. I am sorry man, I am just stuck .

Comment: maybe I should, there could be a pattern thanks, let me go try it out for a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do for this kind of "unorthodox" question is to get familiar enough with the question so that you "understand" it. Check each part of the condition. Can I feel a pattern? Are there some implications? Check the target. How can I connect the target to the conditions? What are the simple cases and extreme cases? You just continue to grope in the dark room, finding/imagining/trying all possibilities.

While I was trying to construct a counterexample, it occurs to me it could happen the only choice of subsequence $B$ with $2022 \geq b_{i + 1} - b_i \geq 1$ is $A$ itself, or a contiguous subsequence of $A$. That leads to my answer below.

---

Here is a counterexample.

Let $a_i=2010i+\begin{cases}2&\text{if }i\text{ is odd}\\5&\text{if } i\text{ is even}\end{cases}$.

$$2010+2,\, 2010\times2+5,\, 2010\times3+2,\, 2010\times4+5,\,\cdots$$
Since any two non-adjacent elements of $A$ are more than $2022$ apart, a subsequence of $A$ with adjacent elements no more than $2022$ apart must be a contiguous subsequence of $A$.

- Any $3$ consecutive elements of $A$ are relative prime, since any element of $A$ is not divisble by $3$, any element at even index is not divisble by $2$ and the difference of the adjacent differences between adjacent elements is $\pm6$.
- Elements of $A$ at odd indices are divisible by $2$. Elements of $A$ at even indices are divisible by $5$.

Comment: I was trying too hard to look for a proof so I didn't think to look for counter-example 